# Laravel: display difference between two dates in blade

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-blade, date-difference

I want to know if it is possible to show in a blade view the difference between the system date and a record of the database with date format ($ticket->start_date) without using Carbon.

For example (I know, it is not working)

```
<td>{{ diff(date('Y-m-d'), strtotime($ticket->start_date))}}</td>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got two separate problems here:

First: how do you diff two dates. You can go high-tech or low-tech here. If you don't want to use Carbon, I suggest going low-tech:

```
<?php
// Note, this gives you a timestamp, i.e. seconds since the Epoch.
$ticketTime = strtotime($ticket->start_date);

// This difference is in seconds.
$difference = $ticketTime - time();
```

At this point, you've got to decide how you want to output the difference. In seconds? In hours?

```
Difference: {{ $difference }} seconds

Difference: {{ round($difference / 3600) }} hours

Difference: {{ round($difference / 86400) }} days
```

You'll have to do extra engineering if you want something as pretty as `Carbon::diffForHumans()`.

Second: This now becomes a question for you whether this is too much code for your front-end. Obviously you could reduce all of the above to a one-liner in PHP, but your co-workers may not appreciate how unreadable it becomes:

```
{{ round((strtotime($ticket->start_date) - time()) / 3600) }} hours
```

**Caveats**

Using timestamps ducks the issue of dealing with timezones. For a bunch of use cases, this is sufficient; for others this is woefully inadequate. But if you want to deal with timezones, you're definitely better off using Carbon, which is better than using PHP's DateTime, but up to you.

Comment: I choice your recommendation, it's easy and practice, thanks so much

Answer (score 6):

**function**

`date_diff()`

**Parameters**

There are Two paramers.
You need to pass `DateTmime` objects to those parameters.

**Returns**

This function return a `DateInterval` object.
You can format `DateInterval` object using `format()` function.

**Example**

```
<td>{{ date_diff(new \DateTime($ticket->start_date), new \DateTime())->format("%m Months, %d days"); }}</td>
```

you can type anything in this `format()` string.

this example format returns something like `"9 Months, 18 days"`

**DateInterval Object**

this is an example of `DateInterval` object.
you can access these properties via `format()` function posted as below.

```
  interval: + 9m 18d 02:27:21.488037
  +"y": 0
  +"m": 9
  +"d": 18
  +"h": 2
  +"i": 27
  +"s": 21
  +"f": 0.488037
  +"weekday": 0
  +"weekday_behavior": 0
  +"first_last_day_of": 0
  +"invert": 0
  +"days": 291
  +"special_type": 0
  +"special_amount": 0
  +"have_weekday_relative": 0
  +"have_special_relative": 0
```

Comment: I appreciate that, it's very helpful, but for a unknown reason this change the style of the web

Comment: I'm so sorry, there was a little mistake when i write the answer. do you see that the `date_diff()` function is wrapped inside a `dd()` function. that was the mistake. remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Please use Carbon lib which is part of laravel.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

```
dd( \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diff( \Carbon\Carbon::parse('your db datetime') ) );
```

Example:

```
dd( \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diff( \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-12-12 00:00:00') ) );
```

Comment: This is obviously the ideal way, but OP say 'without Carbon'.